# XSD schema - namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

What is the importance of a namespace in a XSD schema? Why is namespace used in a schema?
It often resembles a URL which doesn't point to anything.

Can anyone please give more insight on the namespaces and their significance with an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI used as the namespace signifier does not have to actually point to anything. It is merely intended as a semi-human-readable unique identifier to that particular namespace. It often does look like a URL, but it doesn't have to be; the spec specifies URI, so it could be a URN, for example, in which case it definitely would not point to anything.

As for why namespaces are used, they enable mixing multiple schemas in a single XML document, while still ensuring that even if schemas have identically-named elements, it can still be determined which namespace a particular element belongs to. For example, the [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/?v=elements) namespace is used to assign metadata to various resources. Sure, you could just have this information as part of your own schema, but by using DC elements, you are using a well-established set of elements and attributes that are understood by many more tools. DC can be added on to HTML, RDF, Atom, and many other XML-based schemas.

You can read more about XML namespaces [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).